# What is the Python Equivalent of R's rbeta() Function?

Tags: python, r, ab-testing, scipy.stats, beta-distribution

I'm trying to find the Python equivalent of R's `rbeta()` function in order to do some A/B testing. This is the code in `R`:

```
a <- 50
notA <- 200
b <- 200
notb <-400

trials <- 100000

alpha <- 1
beta <- 4

a.samples <- rbeta(trials, a+alpha, notA+beta)
b.samples <- rbeta(trials, b+alpha, notB+beta)

a_wins <- sum(a.samples > b.samples) / trials
b_wins <- sum(b.samples > a.samples) / trials

print(a_wins)
print(b_wins)
```

In this `R` example, **B** wins more than 99% of the time.

This is what I'm trying as the Python equivalent:

```py
import scipy.stats as stats

a = 50
notA = 200
b = 200
notB =400

trials = 100000

alpha = 1
beta = 4

# Random data on which to calculate probability density
inputs = []
inputs = stats.beta(alpha, beta).rvs(size=trials) 

aSamples = stats.beta(a+alpha, notA+beta).pdf(inputs)
bSamples = stats.beta(b+alpha, notB+beta).pdf(inputs)

aWins = sum(aSamples > bSamples) / trials
bWins = sum(bSamples > aSamples) / trials

print("A", aWins)
print("B", bWins)
```

In the Python equivalent, **A** wins 75% of the time.

My guess is that the problem arises with `inputs`, the random stats on which the probability density is calculated. They're generated here with the `.rvs()` method of `scipy.stats.beta`. I've also tried the random number module and `np.linspace()` to no avail. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

---

@user20650 solved it in the comments. Calling `.pdf()` is a redundant step. The function `scipy.stats.beta().rvs()` is the Python equivalent of R's `rbeta()` function. The correct code then should read:

```py
aSamples = stats.beta(a+alpha, notA+beta).rvs(trials)
bSamples = stats.beta(b+alpha, notB+beta).rvs(trials)
```

Thank you everyone who replied. This was melting my head all day yesterday.

Comment: Have you tried `np.random.beta`?

Comment: To amplify SamR's suggestion, try doing a search on: python beta distribution

Comment: From a glance; the two approaches are not equivalent. In R, you sample then sum, in python you sample, calculate pdf of these values, then sum

Comment: Thank you @user20650, you have solved it. Adding the `.pdf()` methods were redundant steps. I've updated my initial post with the answer, in the hope that's the correct way of doing things hereabouts now.